Proof that it is impossible to build more than 2 different tracks of a closed railroad with 8 curved tracks of 45 degrees each and 2 straight tracks.
My child received this train with 8 curved tracks at 45 degrees and 2 straight tracks for her birthday. And I wondered whether it is possible to build more than 2 different sections of a closed track.

I don't think it is, based on the following proof of contradiction. I would like to know if my proof is correct.
Assertion: It is possible with a maximum of 10 tracks, where 8 are curved at 45 degrees and 2 are straight.
Statement 0: The straight tracks have an angle of curvature of 0 degrees.
Statement 1: A closed track has an interior angle of 360 degrees.
Statement 2: 8 tracks curved at 45 degrees are the minimum number of tracks to build a closed track, because 360 degrees divided by 45 degrees equals 8.
Statement 3: The first track consists of 8 curved tracks and forms a circle.

The second track consists of 8 curved tracks and 2 straight tracks in between.

Statement 4: Another track can only exist if I have a curved track to the outside.

This reduces the interior angle by less than 360 degrees. So I need an additional curved track to get reach 360 degrees, thus a closed track.
However, statement 4 is a contradiction to the claim that I only need a maximum of 8 curved tracks. This means that 8 curved and 2 straight tracks are not enough to build more than 2 different railroad lines. Therefore, 2 different railroad lines are the maximum number of railroad lines that I can build with 8 curved and 2 straight tracks.
Is this a valid proof? If not, could you give me a hint how to proof (or disproof) that it is possible to build at least 3 tracks out of 8 curved and 2 straight tracks?

You've proven fairly well that you have to have to include all eight curved tracks. But you haven't eliminated the following cases:

1 straight track
2 straight tracks, but not opposite one another

These aren't necessarily hard to eliminate, but you still need to do so for completeness.
